# Java UOM java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ONE

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jsr

I'm experiencing some version confusion with Java Units of Measurement (UOM). I have a

```
import tec.uom.se.AbstractUnit;

public class Class0 {
    /**
     * Is an {@link AbstractUnit} in order to be serializable as {@code @Basic}
     * with JPA.
     */
    private AbstractUnit<?> unit;

    public Class0() {
    }

    public Class0(AbstractUnit<?> unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public AbstractUnit<?> getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(AbstractUnit<?> unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

which I'm serializing with

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.opower.unitsofmeasure.UnitJacksonModule;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import tec.uom.se.AbstractUnit;
import static tec.uom.se.unit.Units.SQUARE_METRE;

public class TheTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new UnitJacksonModule());
        Class0 value = new Class0((AbstractUnit) SQUARE_METRE);
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
        assertEquals("m²", json);
    }
}
```

while using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opower.unitsofmeasure</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-unitsofmeasure</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>tec.uom</groupId>
    <artifactId>uom-se</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

That fails due to

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ONE
    at systems.uom.ucum.UCUM.<clinit>(UCUM.java:114)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at tec.uom.se.format.SymbolMap.<init>(SymbolMap.java:115)
    at tec.uom.se.format.SymbolMap.of(SymbolMap.java:142)
    at systems.uom.ucum.format.UCUMFormat$Parsing.<clinit>(UCUMFormat.java:416)
    at systems.uom.ucum.format.UCUMFormat.getInstance(UCUMFormat.java:106)
    at com.opower.unitsofmeasure.UnitJacksonModule$UnitJsonSerializer.serialize(UnitJacksonModule.java:56)
    at com.opower.unitsofmeasure.UnitJacksonModule$UnitJsonSerializer.serialize(UnitJacksonModule.java:42)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3893)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3207)
    at de.richtercloud.jackson.unit.serialization.TheTest.test(TheTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

It's not obvious to my why this fails, I suspect a version or implementation conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed by switching to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>tec.uom</groupId>
    <artifactId>uom-se</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```